# How to add GCP instances to AWS load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Majority of my servers are on AWS for which I am using classic load balancer. I have few instances running on GCP too. How to add those GCP instances to AWS load balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot with the Classic Load Balancer. You can with the new Network Load Balancer provided that your Google instances are reachable via public IP addresses.

[EDIT after @michael's comment]

I have not actually tested NLB with Google instances. From the Amazon documentation you can load balance Amazon resources with on premises resources using IP addresses. I am assuming that this means that Google instances would be supported if they have public IP address.

Relevant text:

**Load Balancing using IP addresses as Targets**

You can load balance any application hosted in AWS or on-premises using IP addresses of the application backends as targets. This allows load balancing to an application backend hosted on any IP address and any interface on an instance. Each application hosted on the same instance can have an associated security group and use the same port. You can also use IP addresses as targets to load balance applications hosted in on-premises locations (over a Direct Connect connection) and EC2-Classic (using ClassicLink). The ability to load balance across AWS and on-prem resources helps you migrate-to-cloud, burst-to-cloud or failover-to-cloud.

[Load Balancing using IP addresses as Targets](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/#details)

Comment: Public IP addresses? (RFC-1918 Private, I thought...)

Comment: @Michael. Good comment. I have updated my answer with more information. The specific comment by Amazon regarding Direct Connect now has me thinking ...

Comment: Thanks.  Absent this, HAProxy in EC2 behind ALB would allow this to work over the Internet.